# How do ink droplets passing through two charged metal plates become charged as well?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

In the working mechanism of an inkjet printer, I came to know that ink droplets in the form of a stream pass through two charged parallel metal plates ( like a parallel plate capacitor) and while passing they acquire charge. I wonder, How?
I could not figure out how do they get charged? do they touch the plates? or something else?
 ( I have searched on internet but could not find a specific answer)

Answer (score 1):

An electron gun is used to shoot electrons at the ink which then gives the ink droplets a negative charge, varying based on where the ink needs to go. Then, the charged ink droplet passes between two metal plates, which deflect the ink to its appropriate location on the paper. The ink does not acquire charge from the metal plates, but from the electron gun.

Here is a link to a website with more information: https://thetartan.org/2011/9/12/scitech/htw.

Hope this helps!